# Silverlight Custom Control in F# DefaultStyleKey

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, f#, custom-controls

Wondering how to accomplish setting the Style xaml with the code in F#.  The code is simple enough:

```
this.DefaultStyleKey <- typeof<MyControl>
```

In a C# project the build options allow you to mark the XAML as a resource custom build command of: MSBuild:Compile

I don't see it in the properties panel, so I tried to add it by hand to the project file myself...

Any ideas? The application loads - the custom control has no output (but the code executes).

Thanks

UPDATE:

I checked the manifests and the resource was included as expected between my project and the project I am porting...  Looking for a next step.

UPDATE 2:

Well it may be included in the manifest OK - but it is not being "compiled" as the C# version of the project throws an error in the build process when I malform the XML while the F# version allows the malformed XML to be brought into the application.

UPDATE 3:

Loading the XAML is fine now (i guess) however I am having some issues with the properties of the control:

```
 static member ItemsProperty : DependencyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Items",
            typeof<MyMenuItemCollection>,
            typeof<MyMenu>,
            null);

 member this.Items
        with get () : MyMenuItemCollection = this.GetValue(MyMenu.ItemsProperty) :?> MyMenuItemCollection
        and set (value: MyMenuItemCollection) = this.SetValue(MyMenu.ItemsProperty, value);
```

The problem occurs on access:

```
for menuItem in this.Items do
    let contentElement: FrameworkElement = menuItem.Content
```

where I get a null pointer exception on this.Items; however I have it initialized in the constructor:

```
do
    this.Items <- new CoolMenuItemCollection()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# style of compilation of XAML files is not supported by the F# tools for Visual Studio, so there is no way to get the same behavior as in C#. I think you have two options:

- Create a C# project with XAML files and reference F# library which implements the core functionality (or reference C# library from F# and load user interface from the C# library in your F# application)
- Use `XamlReader` object ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx)) and load the XAML file (embedded in resources in the simple way) programmatically. You won't get any of the C#-compiler generated features (e.g. named properties for all objects with `x:Name`), but otherwise, it should work in the usual way.

Comment: Is this the same XAML reader I used for the main page?  I have a basic app running 100% f# silverlight 3.0.  I am stuck implmenting the cusom control.

On the app I compile the XAML and load it in my implementation of th Application object.  Easy enough everything works;

The custom control example I am porting (a menu component with dancing icons) contains an XAML that defines the basic style of the control.  protected Object DefaultStyleKey 

from what I understand (and it is very little) the property takes a string which represents the "compiled" XAML  for the default style XAML.

Comment: Perhaps using the style property of the control.  I can embed the XAML as a resource and load like i did for the application object.